# Facebook Graph API: how to add a caption to an image you upload?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I am trying to post an image to an album on facebook and place a description with the image.
I can upload the image to an album, but i can't seem to add the description.

Here is the code I use:

```
// prepare the curl post fields
$batch = sprintf('[{"method":"POST", "relative_url":"%1$s/photos", "attached_files":"file1", "message":"caption"}]', $album_id);  

$post_fields = array(
'batch' => $batch,
'access_token' => $access_token,
'file1' => '@' . $image_abs_path,
'caption' => 'image caption goes here"
);
$uri = 'https://graph.facebook.com';

$curl = curl_init( $uri );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );  
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields );  

$raw_data = curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close( $curl );

$data = json_decode( $raw_data, $assoc = TRUE );
```

I also tried with a post-field called "name", but when I use this I get an empty array as a result. The image will not be added to the album when I use this post-field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your $batch:

```
$batch = sprintf('[{"method":"POST", "relative_url":"%1$s/photos", "attached_files":"file1", "body" : "message=Your image caption"}]', $album_id);
```

Ref: [Batch Upload](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/)
Hope it helps